# immutablejs & merge with new key

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have the 2 map objects (One is initial state & one from Network ) and I need to merge the intial state with data received from network. However, i keep `"hideDetails": true` to handle the state in the client side and others from server end.

```
//initial state
var j = Immutable.fromJS({
  "staffs": {
    "hasRecievedData": false,
    "addingNewStaff": false,
    "data": {
      "0": {
        "name" : null,
        "age" : null,
        "designation" : null,
        "email" : null,
        "hideDetails": true
      }
    }
  }
});

// data from network
var m = Immutable.fromJS({
  "staffs" : {
    "0" : {
      "name" : "name1",
      "age" : "23",
      "designation" : "work1",
      "email" : "aliasson@abcd.com"
    },
    "1" : {
      "name" : "name2",
      "age" : "22",
      "designation" : "work2",
      "email" : "aliassson@abcd.com"
    }
  }
});
```

I want to merge these two and get the new states as below,

```
var m = Immutable.fromJS({
  "staffs" : {
    "hasRecievedData": false,
    "addingNewStaff": false,
    "0" : {
      "name" : "name1",
      "age" : "23",
      "designation" : "work1",
      "email" : "aliasson@abcd.com",
      "hideDetails": true
    },
    "1" : {
      "name" : "name2",
      "age" : "22",
      "designation" : "work2",
      "email" : "aliassson@abcd.com",
      "hideDetails": true
    }
  }
});
```

How can I achieve it using Merge functions?

Update1:

Not sure this is correct or not, however I get the result with this,

```
f = j.merge({
  hasRecievedData: true,
  data:  m.get("staffs").map(function(x){
    return x.set("hideDetails",true);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From ImmutableJS docs:

```
var map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4});
var map2 = Immutable.Map({c:10, a:20, t:30});
var obj = {d:100, o:200, g:300};
var map3 = map1.merge(map2, obj);
// Map { a: 20, b: 2, c: 10, d: 100, t: 30, o: 200, g: 300 }
```